# onCreate() runs for the first time

Tags: android, oncreate

Is there a code with which I can test if the onCreate() was called for the first time?

for example

```
if (condition) {
 code that runs if the app runs for the first time 
}else{
 code that runs if activity is started because of configuration changes, orientation changes...
}
```

Comment: declare an variable i at the top. Then do incrementing i for each oncreate method is called. if 1 == 1, then.......

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved the problem but don't know if that is the right/only way

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Log.d("SEBA", "onCreate in if");
    }else {
        Log.d("SEBA", "onCreate in else");
    }}
```

Comment: It might be the right way, but what are you trying to do? Besides logging it ;)